# Node.js not responding to API calls with my app? Working perfectly during development environment, however not when hosted

Tags: node.js, vue.js, hosting

Trying to make my first Vue application, simple game with MEVN stack. Working perfect interacting with backend on development environment, however when hosting it doesn't fetch the data from the server.
Anyone able to point out what I have incorrect with the below?

More info below:

File structure:

/root
 |- config.js 
 |- server.js 
 |- package.json + package-lock.json 
 |- client/ 
  |- vue.config.json 
  |- ... (rest of dist, src, node_modules, public etc.) 
 |- models/ 
  |- Elf.js + HighScore.js 
 |- routes/ 
  |- api/ 
   |- elf.js + highScore.js

config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  hostUrl: process.env.HOST_URL,
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,
};
```

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { PORT, mongoURI } = require("./config.js");
// routes
const Player = require("./routes/api/player");
const Elf = require("./routes/api/elf");
const HighScore = require("./routes/api/highScore");
// cors is a middleware that allows us to make requests from our frontend to our backend
const cors = require("cors");
// morgan is a middleware that logs all requests to the console
const morgan = require("morgan");
// body-parser is a middleware that allows us to access the body of a request
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

app.use(cors());

// use tiny to log only the request method and the status code
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// chek if we are in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // check if we are in production mode
  app.use(express.static("client/dist"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));
  });
}

// test if server is running and connected to mongoDB
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("Hello World!");
// });

// use routes
app.use("/api/", Player);
app.use("/api/", Elf);
app.use("/api/", HighScore);

mongoose
  .connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected..."))
  .then(() => {
    // log uri to console
    console.log(`MongoDB connected to ${mongoURI}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at ${PORT}`);
});
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "week1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore 'client/'",
    "client": "npm run serve --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Running within my dev environment at root dir using 'npm run dev', the app works flawlessly send/ receive data from mongoDB during this time. This starts up http://localhost:8080/. Also tried install of 'npm install -g serve' and running 'serve -s dist', this starts up serving at localhost:36797 and working flawlessly too.

I have tried to setup on Vercel & Render, both giving me the same issue where I'm not getting much feedback and the data isn't being fetched. Anyone else has this issue before?

Comment: Are you sure your MongoDB database is accessible from the remote server?

Comment: I'm fairly certain, I am adding the .env variable for the MONGO_URI to the sections as required on both hosting sites. Also remembering to add the quotations around the string in the input field. (have tried with quotes and without to be sure).
Adding the mongodb string with admin rights and open connections to 0.0.0.0/0 should be suffice from every guide I've been through so far but must be missing something else I would have thought..

Do you know if PORT needs to be set to anything inparticular from the .env? currently it is blank so should be defaulting to the 3000

Comment: When hosted you usually do work with either 80 or 443, but you may be listening to the others ones for sure. One thing to know is that Vercel is out of the equation (no VPS there). As for Render, it should be able to work nicely. Not sure which versions of Node you're using locally/on production too, double check that one. Maybe give a try to Heroku too. Otherwise, do you have any errors in the console/server logs?

Comment: I have been trying Heroku for the past couple of hours at least and still no avail.
https://elf-invasion.herokuapp.com/
TypeError: e.data.sort is not a function
    at Proxy.mounted (SplashScreen.vue:17:10)

This is the one error that appears on all 3, believe that to just be the result of not fetching any data so the array is empty and nothing to display. Doesn't appear when running locally and getting data correctly.
I network get error that JS is disabled when trying to fetch the data from Heroku and Render.. response is a string of HTML and not object array

Comment: Where is `data.sort` used? Something `undefined` somewhere.

Comment: It was sorting the array that it receives from the backend. I just moved the sorting to the backend so the array is already sorted before it makes it to the front and still having issue of no data.
I just get back a string of html text that displays"We're sorry but client doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." That is why the sort error was happening

Comment: You have your answer. The JS is either disabled on the page, you don't have your server running for the frontend (like with `serve`) or something alike.

Comment: Hey Kissu, can you see any discrepancy with the commands in package.json? Running them within my dev environment including (serve) it works flawlessly! Just having the issue when going to host so I am extremely stumped. And yes, my JS is enabled in Chrome.

Comment: Not sure what is not working exactly since there are 2 things going on at the same time. I recommend that you debug step by step. Take the backend first, host it and check if it's working properly. Then try the frontend? And mix them both. Debugging everything at the same time will not work. Where are you hosting your backend and your frontend btw? Your Nuxt app is used as SPA-only, SSR or SSG?